# Where are the Fairy Fountains?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time

I am playing Ocarina of Time on the 3DS, and I vaguely recall there being a fairy fountain somewhat close to each dungeon/temple. Is that true?

Where are the fairy fountains?

Comment: Do you mean the ones with Great Fairies?

Comment: No, just the regular sort that I can get fairies and put them in bottles.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are quite a few fountains overall, so they're fairly scattered. You're correct that some are close to dungeons, however not all dungeons have a fountain close by (e.g Water Temple) and not all fountains are near dungeons (e.g Hyrule Field).

Rather than copy out text, there's a list of locations for Great Fairy Fountains [here](http://uk.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-ocarina-of-time-3d/Great_Fairy_Fountains) and ordinary Fairy Fountains [here](http://uk.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-ocarina-of-time-3d/Pink_Fairy_Fountains). This is for Ocarina of Time 3DS, but I don't know if any of the locations have changed since the N64 verson.

Comment: consider adding the location info into your answer in case the links ever go bad, which happens a lot. +1

Answer (score 4):

Since you're just looking for healing fairies, you can simply get some by playing e.g. Zelda's Lullaby in front of a Gossip Stone ([source](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Fairy#The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Ocarina_of_Time)). You can also play the Song of Storms to have a different fairy emerge which cannot be bottled but refills your magic, by the way.